# Converting mysql query to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql query from mysql which converts the value which is saved in decimal into dot (.). How do I convert it to support SQL Server ? It is the SUM(IF -- Query.

```
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
SUM( IF( measurements.title =  'T_Temperatur', CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ), null ) ) AS Temperatur
FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
INNER JOIN pools ON measure_routine.pool_id = pools.id
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;
```

Mysql result:

[image]

This is SQL server error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: `IF` is not valid. You might want to look into `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SQL Standard [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression :

```
SELECT routines.date, routines.time, 
SUM( CASE WHEN measurements.title =  'T_Temperatur' THEN CAST( REPLACE( routines.value,  ',',  '.' ) AS DECIMAL( 18, 2 ) ) ELSE NULL END) AS Temperatur
FROM routines
INNER JOIN measure_routine ON routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id
INNER JOIN measurements ON measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id
INNER JOIN pools ON measure_routine.pool_id = pools.id
GROUP BY routines.date, routines.time
ORDER BY routines.date, routines.time;
```